# Masking a pandas column based on another column with slightly different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

So what I have is two Pandas dataframes in Python with a large number of xyz-coordinates. One of them will be used to mask/remove some coordinates in the other one, but the problem is that the coordinates are very slightly different so that I cannot simply remove duplicates. As an example, let's say they look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df1.x = [104245, 252355, 547364, 135152]
df1.y = [842714, 135812, 425328, 124912]
df1.z = [125125, 547574, 364343, 346372]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df2.x = [104230, 547298]
df2.y = [842498, 424989]
df2.z = [124976, 364001]
```

What I then want is for the first and second xyz-rows in df2 to remove the first and third row in df1. My idea was to create new columns with rounded values, compare those, and remove based on those. It would look something like this:

```
df1['id'] = np.linspace(0,len(df1)-1,len(df1))
df2['id'] = np.linspace(0,len(df2)-1,len(df2))

df3 = df1.round({'x': -3, 'y': -3, 'z': -3})
df4 = df2.round({'x': -3, 'y': -3, 'z': -3})

df5 = df3.merge(df4, on=['x', 'y', 'z'], how='inner')
df6 = df1[~df1.index.isin(df5.id_x)]
```

This works fine to remove some of the values, but often they round to different places. I was hoping with help if there is a better method to mask those values which are simply closest in all three coordinates. Maybe that it finds the closest xyz-pair between df1 and df2 and masks those pairs. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Compute the euclidean distance then remove rows where the distance is lower than D of the nearest points from df2 with KDTree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting to consider the individual distances between the coordinates:

```
# convert DataFrames to numpy arrays
a1 = df1.to_numpy()
a2 = df2.to_numpy()

# define a distance below which the coordinates are considered equal
thresh = 500

# compute the distances, identify matches on all coordinates
matches = (abs(a1[:,None]-a2) <= thresh).all(axis=-1)

idx1, idx2 = np.where(matches)
# (array([0, 2]), array([0, 1]))

out = df1.drop(df1.index[idx1])
```

To consider the euclidean distance between the points (taking into account all coordinates simultaneously), use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

thresh = 1000

matches = cdist(a1, a2) <= thresh

idx1, idx2 = np.where(matches)

out = df1.drop(df1.index[idx1])
```

Output:

```
        x       y       z
1  252355  135812  547574
3  135152  124912  346372
```

##### removing the single point from `df1` that is closest to each row of `df2` and below a threshold

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

thresh = 1000

dist = cdist(a1, a2)

idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=0)

out = df1.drop(df1.index[idx[dist[idx, np.arange(len(a2))] <= thresh]])
```

If the distance doesn't matter and you only want to remove the closest point:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dist = cdist(a1, a2)

idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=0)

out = df1.drop(df1.index[idx])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works fine in some of the cases, but using a threshold means that sometimes points that are similar are removed when they should not be. What I mainly want is to remove the single xyz-point from df1 which is closest to each one in df2. There might be points that are further away but would be included in the threshold when they should not be otherwise. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried @Corralien's approach with KDTree? This should select the single closest point (`k=1`). An other approch with my solution would be to select the point with smallest distance per row (using `idxmin` for instance)

Comment: @MarcusK.: My updated answer contains a solution to the new problem you have.

Comment: I guess you can remove `thresh = 1000` from your last solution, @mozway! :-)

Comment: @mozway, thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately since the dataframe is so large (tens of millions of points), my computer does not have enough memory to store all of the information in those solutions. Either it must handle each point individually and remove it from memory after or the threshold method will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

# compute the distance with the nearest distance from df2
distances, indices = KDTree(df2).query(df1, k=1)

# keep row if the distance is greater than 3000
out = df1[distances >= 3000]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        x       y       z
1  252355  135812  547574
3  135152  124912  346372
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses `numpy broadcasting`:

```
thresh = 1000
df1[~np.any(
    np.sqrt(np.sum((df1.values - df2.values[:, None])**2, axis=2)) < thresh,
    axis=0 )]
```

---

If we want to remove the closest points, we can use:

```
df1.iloc[df1.index.difference(np.argmin(
    np.sqrt(np.sum((df1.values - df2.values[:, None])**2, axis=2)), axis=1)), :]
```

---

Output:

```
        x       y       z
1  252355  135812  547574
3  135152  124912  346372
```